# Keyevent in Windows

Tags: c++, windows, events, keyboard, handle

is it possible to get an event for pressed key in Windows (XP)? I have a thread, it has a while(1)-loop  and i print some data there. It must be synchronize thats why i use WaitForMultipleObjects(2, events, FALSE, INFINITE);
events is an array of handles and it contains 2 handles. One of them is an event from the other thread that signals, that the server got a new message and the other one should signal me that the user pressed a key (1-7). How can i get this second handle/event?

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects`. This can retrieve messages as well, such as `WM_KEYDOWN`. You don't need a `HANDLE` for key events.

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement a message loop to listen for `WM_KEYDOWN` or `WM_KEYUP`. Then you should call the appropriate method.

Answer (score 0):

In your program, you should have a thread handling events arriving to your program, such as keyboard, mouse etc. In that thread, you can detect if a keyboard event pressing or releasing the key you are interested in arrives. If so, you signal your other thread.